# What COM error occurs if TerminateProcess() is called on a local out-of-process server during a COM call?

Tags: com, win32com

In the middle of a COM call to a local out-of-process COM server, while the client process's thread is blocking waiting for the call to return, if `TerminateProcess()` is called on the local out-of-process server by a third process, what will the client see (under which circumstances, if multiple possibilities)?

`RPC_S_CALL_FAILED`? `RPC_S_COMM_FAILURE`? `RPC_S_SERVER_UNAVAILABLE`?

And separately, will `pywin32`'s `win32com` ever handle or wrap this?

Comment: Become that third process, call `TerminateProcess()` on your server and see what happens? ([`RPC_E_SERVER_DIED`](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20140807-00/?p=313)?)

Comment: Not able to directly replicate, but I found `CO_E_SERVER_EXEC_FAILURE` during initial dispatch that launched the remote server, and `RPC_S_CALL_FAILED` during a later method.